# "Well-loved use" vs "frequent and fond use"

Tags: writing-style, word-choice, grammar

What makes more sense, grammar-wise?

> Mama admires the butter churn; the “sinks” in its “beautiful light yellow wood from … where Big Dee and Stash had lived” testify to its well-loved use.

> Mama admires the dasher; the “sinks” in its “beautiful light yellow wood from … where Big Dee and Stash had lived” testify to its frequent and fond use.

Or do they both not make sense?

(For context, Mama's talking about how there's all these sinks in the wood because people would push their hands into it and such. The dasher has been used a ton over the last few generations in their family, it's almost an heirloom of sorts)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the context from such a short extract, but possibly other people will have suggestions regardless :)

Comment: Hi Manaal - What does "dasher" mean? It sounds like it might be a piece of wooden furniture.  What do you mean by "sinks?" It sounds like you might be referring to indentations of some sort. I'd rewrite this as "Mama admires the box from where Big Dee and Stash had lived. The indentations in its wood speak to its frequent and fond use.

Comment: Is there a reason you have quotes around "beautiful light yellow wood..."?

Comment: hello! @DM_with_secrets, I added some context. I hope it helps! The quotes are there because I'm analyzing a short story ("Everyday Use")

Comment: @rolfedh ah sorry, miswrote it. So a dasher is something used in a butter churn. Sinks in the wood refers to how the dasher's frequent use basically eroded the churn.

Comment: @ManaalSiddiqui I recommend providing enough context for readers to understand the terminology (e.g., dasher)  you use. Your use of "sinks" is off. I'd recommend indentations or some synonym instead.

Comment: "sinks" was not my word choice. It's from the short story I'm analyzing